# SQL commands Colliding between users, while clicking a button at the same time, ASP.NET 4.5 WebForms VB

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

this is my first question here on StackOverflow but this site has been a great help to me in the past.

I have taken on a legacy project at my current job, and it is a ASP.net 4.5 WebForms application running on a Windows Server 2008 R2, with a SQL Server 2008 R2 database behind it.

Currently we have an issue where if two or more users click on a button that executes a SQL Command they get one of two errors:

"*A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.*"

or

"*ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open.*"

The first issue can be cleared up if the user refreshes, the second issue requires the AppPool to be recycled on the web server.

Here is an example of a call to the database:

```
Public Function OpenSQLConn() As String

    If SQLConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        SQLConn.ConnectionString = ConnStr
        SQLConn.Open()
    End If

    OpenSQLConn = SQLConn.DataSource.ToString

End Function

Public Function CloseSQLConn() As String

    If SQLConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        SQLConn.Close()
    End If

    CloseSQLConn = SQLConn.Database.ToString

End Function
Public Sub getDataSet(ByRef ds As DataSet, ByVal dataTable As String, ByVal queryString As String)

    OpenSQLConn()
    Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand
    With sqlCmd
        .CommandText = queryString
        .CommandTimeout = 0
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .Connection = SQLConn
    End With

    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
    da.Fill(ds, dataTable)
    CloseSQLConn()
End Sub
Public Function executeSQL(ByVal queryString As String, Optional ByVal doNotExecuteDebugOnly As Boolean = False) As Boolean

    If SQLConn.ConnectionString = "" Then
        SQLConn.ConnectionString = ConnStr
    End If

    If doNotExecuteDebugOnly = True Then
        Debug.Print("ExecuteSQL, Not Executed: " & queryString)

    End If

    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(queryString, SQLConn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    If SQLConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        SQLConn.Open()
    End If

    da.Fill(ds, "temp")

    executeSQL = True

    SQLConn.Close()

End Function
```

I'm assuming I need to change the way I am accessing SQL, or do something different with the settings on the Servers, but I'm at a loss as to what to change. Any thing would be helpful at this point.

Comment: You shouldn't be leaving your connection open like that.  Also, the DataAdapter can open and close the connection that it needs, so you don't have to manage that.  Based on your code, you are probably not using parameters.  That leaves you open to sql injection and formatting errors.  I would scrap almost all of the posted code.

Comment: It looks like you're sharing a connection object...that's not a good idea to begin with, but that problem is compounded if it's also in a public module. I think it'd be a good idea to modify the code to create a new connection object each time a query needs to be executed, and then disposing it immediately once finished

Comment: I was thinking that I was going to have to do this with Parameters and by scrapping these functions.

By talking to the previous developer these functions came from a .Net 2.0 WinForms desktop application.

Comment: That makes no difference.

Comment: Start using `using` to dispose of those connections and you might just solve the problem accidentally.